# How to type umlauts, ß using a UK Laptop?

Tags: umlaut

I don't have the NumLock key and only have the numbers at the top of my keyboard - not at the side. I have tried to use alt key codes but they haven't worked. I have a UK Qwerty keyboard from Framework if that helps.

Comment: While the headline of the linked duplicate appears German, the question is bi-lingual and most of the answers are English.